# How to call a function from a function pointer?

Tags: c++, function

How can you call a function from only a pointer to the function? For example:

```
void print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;;
}

void run_func(void* func)
{
    func(); // what im trying to do (doesnt actually work)
}

int main()
{
    run_func(print);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Hello World!
```

It's a bit like how `std::thread` creates a thread from the pointer of a variable.

Comment: Are you asking how to call a `void*` that happens to hold a function pointer?  Why did you choose `void*` as the type?

Comment: Two mistakes: `void * func` is a pointer to `void`. `void (*func)()` is a function pointer returning `void` and taking no parameters.

Comment: Are you and [this asker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389681/acces-a-void-function-that-is-inside-an-unique-ptr-array) working on the same homework? Two "I have a function pointer stored in a ludicrous type" questions in the same day makes me think there's an instructor out there handing out comically bad advice.

Comment: `void*` is not a function pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function pointers in function parameter lists need to be wrapped in parentheses. Change the one line, either by wrapping with parentheses or using the typedef'ed function parameter, and your sample works.

```
// Simplifies arcane function parameter synax.
typedef void (*FUNC_TO_RUN)();

void print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;;
}

// Change your parameter as follows. You need to wrap function
// pointers in parantheses.Or, use a typedef.
// void run_func(void *func())  
// void run_func(void (*func)()) // Works, but harder to read
void run_func(FUNC_TO_RUN func)  // Works, easier to read
{
    func(); // what im trying to do (and now works)
}

int main()
{
    run_func(print);
}
```

Comment: I like this code, but an explanation of _what you changed_ and _why you changed it_ would be helpful to both this asker and future readers.

Comment: It's all updated with comments explaining the one change needed to run successfully.

Comment: @Drew Dormann It's been a long time since I posted a full-fledged answer. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: A `typedef` for the function would go a long way to simplifying the code and making the code easier to read.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your parameter type of `run_func` to `void (*func) ()`, which means `func` is a pointer to a void function that takes no parameters.

Corrected code:

```cpp
void print() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

void run_func(void (*func)()) {
    func();
    // or you can call the print function by (*func)();
}

int main() {   
    run_func(print);
    // prints "Hello World!"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::function`:

```cpp
void print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;;
}

void run_func(std::function<void()> f) // f returns void and takes no parameters
{
    f();
}

int main()
{
    run_func(print);
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but can be significantly heavier-weight than the raw stupidity of a function pointer.

Comment: @user4581301 Oh I wasn't sure. How significant is the overhead? I still think the type safety and clarity is worth it in most cases, no?

Comment: @jackylamouette `std::function` does not offer more type safety than a function pointer.

Comment: I'm having trouble demonstrating the difference with a simple example because most of the time the function pointer version is compiled out, but here's something close: https://godbolt.org/z/P71dP6xE9 Function pointer version compiles to a jump. `std::function` version is a jump buried with some extra armour in case the caller passes in a null pointer or other stupidity. It is a bit safer, but how much you need that safety is a coin-toss.